# Getting error in oracle sql developer trying to print xml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlxml, sql-pl

I am trying to print the following XML as

---

PLCO_ID          is A-006884-2

Trt_numc        is 103

Trt_familyc     is 1

Trt_days         is 2513

Neoadjuvant   is 0

---

PLCO_ID          is A-008288-4

Trt_numc       is 104

Trt_familyc    is 1

Trt_days         is 331

Neoadjuvant   is 0

---

Etc. etc.

However, I have been getting an error. I believe my loop is correct as I need to use an implicit cursor for this particular problem. I think I may have to use rpad() in my print to have it print out correctly but I'm not sure. The code is attached below. Thanks in advance for the help!

The XML code is this

[image]

[image]

Comment: please update this question, and include the actual code and error stack as text

Comment: Apologies I have added the XML code above

Comment: you...added more pictures of code, not the actual code

Comment: I have solved the issue, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
    for x in (select j.onepatient.extract('//PLCO_ID/text()').getstringval() as PLCO_ID, 
    j.onepatient.extract('//trt_numc/text()').getstringval()as Trt_numc, j.onepatient.extract('//trt_familyc/text()').getstringval() as Trt_familyc, 
    j.onepatient.extract('//trt_days/text()').getstringval() as Trt_days,j.onepatient.extract('//neoadjuvannt/text()').getstringval() as Neoadjuvant 
    from treatment_xml j)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('PLCO_ID        is: '||x.PLCO_ID ||chr(10) ||'Trt_numc       is: '||x.Trt_numc ||chr(10) ||
        'Trt_familyc    is: ' || x.Trt_familyc || chr(10) || 'Trt_days       is: ' || x.Trt_days|| chr(10)||
        'Neoadjuvant    is: ' || x.Neoadjuvant || chr(10));
    end  loop;
end;/
```

Comment: the way you formatted your answer is how we were trying to get you to format your question...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).